# Por que usar o Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Tenho essa duvida, por que usar o selenium como "teste", ouvir dizer que muitos não usam por ele ser trabalhoso para escrever...mas em diversar vagas de emprego vejo que é pedido conhecimento.

A questão é quando e por que usar o Selenium

Comment: Olá Guilherme: dá uma olhada à tag: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium/info Basicamente é util para fazer testes automáticos ao código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium é um ambiente integrado de desenvolvimento para scripts de testes automatizados. Inicialmente ele foi implementado como uma extensão do Firefox e permite gravar, editar e depurar os testes. O Selenium IDE inclui o Selenium Core , permitindo que você facilmente e rapidamente possa gravar e reproduzir os testes no ambiente real que será executado.

Com isso ele se torna uma ótima ferramenta para testar quase tudo que quiser que esteja na web, é bastante usado em teste para funcionalidades de site ver se está tudo funcionando e respondendo aos conformes até mesmo para brincar com isso (hehehe).

Sintaxe dele é bem fácil de se usar assim como qualquer outra.
A inserção dele no mercado (embora eu só tenha brincado com o mesmo) pode ser para as funcionalidades que falei é mais algumas que pode se pensar (app pra testar logins, bots,etc)